# How do I do these JavaScript date() calls in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, date, math

I need to write a PHP program to get a world population clock value. It will be used with other PHP code for calculations and I need the world population clock real-time estimate for the formula to work.

I've not been able to find this already done in PHP, but I have found this free JavaScript program:
http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/worldpop2.shtml

The problem is I don't know JavaScript and I need it in PHP, so I need some help with some of these functions to understand how to do their equivalent in PHP:

```
function maind()
{
  startdate = new Date()        
  now(startdate.getYear(),startdate.getMonth(),startdate.getDate(),startdate.getHours(),startdate.getMinutes(),startdate.getSeconds())

}
```

What does new `Date()` return to the variable `startdate`? What does the data look like? What is the equivalent function in `PHP`? Is there a more simplified way to do this in PHP? Thanks!

Comment: For the js `date()` this will help you http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_date.asp

Comment: PHP's [`dateTime` class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) provides all the functionality you require.

Comment: @MahmoodRehman Please don't reference W3Schools > http://www.w3fools.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo "The current estimated population is: "
 .number_format(10000000*(560+9*(time()-mktime(0,0,0,1,1,1996))/365/24/60/60));
```

That JavaScript code is *ugly*...

Comment: No... it's concatenating with the string in the previous line. I would've just put `echo` but then it didn't quite fit in the width of the code box ;)

Comment: How can I store that value without the commas in PHP?

Comment: ... Really? You can't figure that out?

Comment: I've not used number_format before I see now.
You know, the result of this code is about 2,000 off from the JavaScript one. Does your math formula need an update?

Comment: The JavaScript one is wrong because apparently whoever wrote it is unaware of the fact that months in JS are zero-based.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are looking for a PHP equivalent.. Go for the [`DateTime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) Class

```
<?php
function maind(){
$date = new DateTime();
echo $date->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
}

maind(); //2014-01-10 10:37:23
```

Answer (score 0):

*I'm assuming that the snippet you have posted is a Javascript code.*

**What does new Date() return to the variable startdate? What does the data look like?**
Well, you can debug any return value using `console.log` function, like this:

```
startdate = new Date();
console.log(startdate);
#=> Fri Jan 10 2014 15:58:10 GMT+0530 (IST) # return value
console.log(startdate.getYear());
# => 114
```

**What is the equivalent function in PHP? Is there a more simplified way to do this in PHP?**
Yes, there is. You can use the function [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) for your purpose:

```
<?php
function maind(){
  $startdate = new DateTime();
  var_dump($startdate);
  echo $date->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
}

maind();
```